# Extension problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be the ring consisting of the upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $M_{1},\,M_{2}$ two $R$-modules defined as follows: for $A=(a_{ij})\in R$, $q\in \mathbb{Q}$   $$A\cdot q= a_{11}q,\,\,\,\,\,\,A\cdot q= a_{22} q$$
>   I want to show that if $0\longrightarrow M_{1}\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow M_{2}\longrightarrow 0$ and  $0\longrightarrow M_{1}\longrightarrow Y\longrightarrow M_{2}\longrightarrow 0$ are two non split exact sequences, then $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$.

I know that this is relevant to $Ext_{1}(M_{2}, M_{1})$, but i am very confused about that. Any ideas? thank you

Comment: What is your background? Have you heard of quiver representations?

Comment: Can you recommend me something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is any ring and $1 = e_1 + ... + e_n$ is a decomposition of $1$ as the sum of pairwise orthogonal idempotents, then any $R$-module $M$ naturally decomposes, as an abelian group, as $M = \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n} e_i M$. If $x\in R$ satisfies $x = e_i x = x e_j$, then the action of $x$ on $M$ annihilates all summands $M_k$ for $k\neq j$, and maps $M_j$ into $M_i$. In this way, $R$-modules can be viewed as $\{1,2,...,n\}$-indexed abelian groups $M = \{M_i\}$ together with maps $M_j\to M_i$ for each $x\in e_i R e_j$ (this is intentionally kept vague at this point).

In your example, $R = \tiny\begin{pmatrix} \ast & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & \ast\end{pmatrix}$ admits a decomposition $1 = e_1 + e_2 + e_3$ with $e_1 := \tiny\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ etc., hence any $R$-module $M$ decomposes as $M = M_1\oplus M_2\oplus M_3$ with $M_i := e_i M$ - since $R$ is a ${\mathbb Q}$-algebra, this is even a decomposition as ${\mathbb Q}$-vector spaces. Moreover, the element $e_{12} := \tiny\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and the analogously defined $e_{13}$ and $e_{23}$ act as ${\mathbb Q}$-linear homomorphisms $\alpha: M_2\to M_1$, $\gamma: M_3\to M_1$ and $\beta: M_3\to M_2$, respectively, and by associativity of the $R$-action, $e_{12} e_{23} = e_{13}$ implies that the composition $M_3\xrightarrow{\beta} M_2\xrightarrow{\alpha} M_1$ equals $M_3\xrightarrow{\gamma} M_1$.

All in all, this means that $R\text{-Mod}$ is equivalent to the category of diagrams of ${\mathbb Q}$-vector spaces of the form $\bullet\leftarrow\bullet\leftarrow\bullet$, with commutative diagrams as morphisms.

In this description, your module $M_2$ corresponds to $0\leftarrow {\mathbb Q}\leftarrow 0$, while $M_1$ corresponds to ${\mathbb Q}\leftarrow 0\leftarrow 0$. Now it is clear that the only extensions between $M_2$ and $M_1$ are of the form $E_\lambda :\equiv {\mathbb Q}\stackrel{\lambda}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}\leftarrow 0$ with $\lambda\in{\mathbb Q}$, and they are non-split if and only if $\lambda\neq 0$. Moreover, $E_\lambda\cong E_\mu$ for $\lambda,\mu\in{\mathbb Q}\setminus\{0\}$ via multiplication by $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ in either the first or second copy of ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Your answer seems accurate and correct, but as i don't know some parts, i want to change it a little bit. I have modified it but i don't know if the following is true:

Comment: Since there is a homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow R$, if $M$ is an $R-$ module then $M$ is a $\mathbb{Q}-$ module i.e. $\mathbb{Q}-$vector space and each $R-$ map is a $\mathbb{Q}-$map i.e $\mathbb{Q}-$linear. Now if $f_{1}:M_{1}\longrightarrow X$ and $f_{2}:X\longrightarrow M_{2}$ then they are of the form $f_{1}(x)=q_{1}x, f_{2}(x)=q_{2}x$ and since the sequence doesn't split $q_{1},q_{2}\neq 0$. Is this right?

Comment: @noether23: You have to specify which morphism $\varphi: {\mathbb Q}\to R$ you are considering: each of the three idempotents $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in $R$ defines one. But you have to be careful: the $\varphi$ are *non-unital*, and hence you can't restrict modules along them. If you want to obtain the decomposition $M=M_1\oplus M_2\oplus M_3$ by means of a restriction functor, consider the (unital!) ring homomorphism ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\hookrightarrow R$ corresponding to the embedding of the diagonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do you think that the injective envelopes of $M_{1},M_{2}$ could help me for the understanding of $e(M_{2},M_{1})$? I know that the computation of inj. envelopes here is something very hard. But what do you think?

Comment: @noether23: For categories of diagrams of vector spaces like your category $R\text{-Mod}$, projectives and injectives can in fact be described *very* explicitly: In your example, the indecomposable projectives are the modules ${\mathbb Q}\leftarrow 0\leftarrow 0$, ${\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}\leftarrow 0$ and ${\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}$ obtained by choosing one of the three vertices in the graph and counting paths *starting* in that vertex.

Comment: @noether23: If you find these things interesting, search for *representations of quivers* and you will find lots of material.

Comment: @noether23: Similarly, the indecomposable injectives are ${\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}$ (injective envelope of $M_1$), $0\leftarrow {\mathbb Q}\stackrel{1}{\leftarrow}{\mathbb Q}$ (injective envelope of $M_2$) and $0\leftarrow 0\leftarrow {\mathbb Q}$ (injective envelope of $M_3$) obtained by choosing one of the three vertices and counting paths *ending* in that vertex.

Comment: I think that i understand what you say, but as set what is for example the injective envelope of $M_{1}$? By this i mean to which set correspond the $\mathbb{Q}\leftarrow\mathbb{Q}\leftarrow\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The underlying ${\mathbb Q}$ vector space of the module that corresponds to ${\mathbb Q}\leftarrow{\mathbb Q}\leftarrow {\mathbb Q}$ is ${\mathbb Q}^{\oplus 3}$, with $e_1,e_2,e_3$ acting as the projections onto the respective summands, and the off-diagonal matrices $e_{12},e_{13},e_{23}$ mapping between them. In fact, it is just the natural module over $R$ given by matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: So we can use what you say for computing $Ext_{1}(M_{2},M_{1}), Ext_{1}(M_{2},M_{2})$?

Comment: Yes, an injective resolution of $M_1$ is given by $M_1\to I_1\equiv({\mathbb Q}\leftarrow{\mathbb Q}\leftarrow{\mathbb Q})\to I_2\equiv(0\leftarrow{\mathbb Q}\leftarrow{\mathbb Q})$, hence $\text{Ext}^1(X,M_1)$ is the cokernel of $\text{Hom}_R(X,I_1)\to\text{Hom}_R(X,I_2)$, i.e. $\text{coker}(X_1^{\ast}\to X_2^{\ast})$ since $\text{Hom}_R(X,I_i)\cong X_i^{\ast}$ where $\ast$ means ${\mathbb Q}$-dual. For $X = M_2$ you get $\text{Ext}^1(M_2,M_1)\cong{\mathbb Q}$ as claimed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question - the $I_i$ are the injectives I defined in my third to last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19955/discussion-between-hanno-and-noether23).